# Is this AWS EC2 hardware (cpu, memory) too old?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2

Is this EC2 hardware too old? Is there a way to select newer hardware(e.g., faster CUP, Memory DDR5) when launching a new EC2 instance?

```
*-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz
          slot: CPU 0
          size: 2500MHz
          capacity: 3500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz

 *-memory
          description: System Memory
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank
             description: DIMM DDR4 Static column Pseudo-static Synchronous Window DRAM 2933 MHz (0.3 ns)
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2933MHz (0.3ns)
```

Comment: What’s the instance type and what purpose are you wondering if it’s too old for? For each category of instance types, the number (usually the second character) indicates the generation, with higher numbers being newer. So M7 instances have newer infrastructure than M6 instances. Look for the highest number for the type category you’re selecting to get the most up to date infrastructure.

Comment: EC2. general purpose server. If DDR5 is popular for EC2, DDR4 is outdated.

Comment: I was looking for the AWS instance type character string. For example, the latest generation (at the time of this comment) of general purpose instances are M7g instances. If you want the newest hardware for general purpose, select an M7g instance of the appropriate size.

Comment: Instance type: t3.medium.  It is not labelled as M1,M2,...

Comment: t3 instances are "current generation" per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html. t4 instances are available if your stuff can run on ARM processors. If you want more RAM and CPU power, a larger instance is the answer. See the chart at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/

Comment: The t instances are burstable, which means they are the most affordable type but you don’t get maximum performance from them 24x7. A lot of workloads do not need maximum performance 24x7 but it’s worth being aware of.

Comment: That hardware is likely adequate for the workloads running on t3 instances. If you need super high performance or low latency you can choose M7a / M7g / C7g / R7iz and similar instances which have the newest CPUs and DDR5 RAM. Your question is really too vague "is the hardware too old". The way to choose newer hardware is by choosing the instance class with the hardware you want.